# Three dimensional Regression Plan with Residuals

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, r

In R, I can make three dimensional Regression plane with residuals with the following command

```
scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)
```

with `scatter3d` function from `car` `R` package.

I need some hints to make the same plot with `tikz`. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
library(car)
Duncan
                   type income education prestige
accountant         prof     62        86       82
pilot              prof     72        76       83
architect          prof     75        92       90
author             prof     55        90       76
chemist            prof     64        86       90
minister           prof     21        84       87
professor          prof     64        93       93
dentist            prof     80       100       90
reporter             wc     67        87       52
engineer           prof     72        86       88
undertaker         prof     42        74       57
lawyer             prof     76        98       89
physician          prof     76        97       97
welfare.worker     prof     41        84       59
teacher            prof     48        91       73
conductor            wc     76        34       38
contractor         prof     53        45       76
factory.owner      prof     60        56       81
store.manager      prof     42        44       45
banker             prof     78        82       92
bookkeeper           wc     29        72       39
mail.carrier         wc     48        55       34
insurance.agent      wc     55        71       41
store.clerk          wc     29        50       16
carpenter            bc     21        23       33
electrician          bc     47        39       53
RR.engineer          bc     81        28       67
machinist            bc     36        32       57
auto.repairman       bc     22        22       26
plumber              bc     44        25       29
gas.stn.attendant    bc     15        29       10
coal.miner           bc      7         7       15
streetcar.motorman   bc     42        26       19
taxi.driver          bc      9        19       10
truck.driver         bc     21        15       13
machine.operator     bc     21        20       24
barber               bc     16        26       20
bartender            bc     16        28        7
shoe.shiner          bc      9        17        3
cook                 bc     14        22       16
soda.clerk           bc     12        30        6
watchman             bc     17        25       11
janitor              bc      7        20        8
policeman            bc     34        47       41
waiter               bc      8        32       10

scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)
```

[image]

```
scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education | type, data=Duncan)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, short of calling R (which some packages can do), no tex-based solution is going to be able to imitate the brevity of the R command for statistical analysis; that is one of R's strong points.

That having been said, here's an attempt to redo your first image (including the statistical analysis) using Asymptote. Note that the statistical analysis requires the [smoothcontour3 package](https://github.com/charlesstaats/smoothcontour3), which you may need to install by hand (i.e., copy the file into your working directory) unless you have a bleeding-edge version of Asymptote.

[image]

The code assumes that your data (including the header) was copied and pasted into a file called `Duncan.dat`. (The header isn't necessary; it's just that I explicitly skip the first line.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=UnifiedRegression}
settings.outformat = "png";
settings.render = 8;
size(10cm);
import graph3;
import smoothcontour3;  // for the leastsquares routine

Billboard.targetsize = true;  // Perspective should not affect the labels.
currentprojection = perspective(60 * (5, 2, 3));

file duncan = input("Duncan.dat");

string headers = duncan;

real[][] independentvars;
real[] dependentvars;

while (!eof(duncan)) {
  string line = duncan;
  string[] entries = split(line);
  if (entries.length < 5) continue;
  string type = entries[1];
  real income = (real)(entries[2]);
  real education = (real)(entries[3]);
  real prestige = (real)(entries[4]);

  // include 1.0 for the residue
  independentvars.push(new real[] {income, education, 1.0});
  dependentvars.push(prestige);
}

real[] coeffs = leastsquares(independentvars, dependentvars, warn=false);
if (coeffs.length == 0) {
  abort("Unable to find regression: independent variables are "
    + "linearly dependent.");
}

real f(pair xy) {
  return coeffs[0] * xy.x  // income
       + coeffs[1] * xy.y  // education
       + coeffs[2];        // residue
}

real xmin = infinity, xmax = -infinity, ymin = infinity, ymax = -infinity;
for (real[] row : independentvars) {
  if (row[0] < xmin) xmin = row[0];
  if (row[0] > xmax) xmax = row[0];
  if (row[1] < ymin) ymin = row[1];
  if (row[1] > ymax) ymax = row[1];
}

// Draw the plane
draw(surface(f, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax)),
     surfacepen=emissive(blue + opacity(0.6)),
     meshpen = blue);

for (int ii = 0; ii < independentvars.length; ++ii) {
  triple pt = (independentvars[ii][0], independentvars[ii][1],
           dependentvars[ii]);
  draw(shift(pt) * unitsphere, material(yellow, emissivepen=0.2*yellow));
  real z = f((pt.x, pt.y));
  if (pt.z > z) draw (pt -- (pt.x, pt.y, z), green);
  else draw(pt -- (pt.x, pt.y, z), red);
}

xaxis3("income", Bounds(Min, Min), InTicks);
yaxis3("education", Bounds(Min, Min), InTicks);
zaxis3("prestige", Bounds(Min, Min), InTicks);
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `pgfplots` package.  It's probably easiest to compute the regression plane in `R.`  A minimal example (without adornments) to get you started is below, where try.dat contains the data you provided.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[only marks] table[x index=2, y index=3,z index=4]{try.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```